# Android native library isn't installed

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm new in NDK. I created the simplest foo library.
When I try to load it with *System.loadLibrary("foo")* I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load foo: findLibrary returned null
```

I checked, *libfoo.so* is present inside APK-file in *lib/armeabi/libfoo.so*.
But it isn't deployed on emulator to */data/data/com.myapp/lib/libfoo.so* during installation of APK-file. I install APK with debug button in Eclipse.

What do I do wrong?

I tried to push it manually to /data/data/com.myapp/lib/. In that case I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: get_lib_extents[742]:   801 - /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libfoo.so is not a valid ELF object
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the native library under libs/[TARGET_ARCH_ABI] where TARGET_ARCH_ABI is armeabi,x86 etc.